# Javascript boolean assignment

Tags: javascript, boolean-operations

I found that in javascript `&=` operator is a bitwise assignement:

```
var test=true;
test&=true;
//here test is an int variable
```

Does boolean assignment exist in javascript?

Is this the only solution?

```
var test=true;
test=test & true;
```

Comment: No, there's no compound assignment for boolean operations in JS. So yes, you have to use `x = x && y` form.

Comment: It's worth nothing that `true & true == true`, `true & false == false` and `false & false == false` - they might not be boolean values, but the equality holds.

Comment: Ok but for example, I used this: $("...").toggleClass("myclass",test) and test was not recognized as boolean and the behaviour of toggleClass was different than expected. This is why I would liketo know if exists the real boolean assignment. In my case I solve with the double exclamation mark to cast it to boolean $("...").toggleClass("myclass",!!test)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a shorthand assignment for booleans so yes you would have to use your outlined solution.

```
var test=true;
test=test & true;
```

This could largely be down to the short-circuiting that occurs with Boolean operations such as with the `&&` operator. If the first value in the `&&` statement is false then it will short circuit and not check any further. That behaviour might not be obvious to everyone so they may have deliberately left out this operator to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, there are logical AND and logical OR assignment operators `&&=` and `||=`:

```
var test = true;
test &&= true;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment